# Instagram API - Comment Reply/Delete deprecated but some of platforms still working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

As you know that Instagram closed

`POST /media/{media-id}/comments`

`DEL /media/{media-id}/comments/comment-id`

these endpoints.So we can't delete or reply any comment through Instagram API anymore. But, agorapulse.com still can delete and reply these comments without any other authentications(bussiness account not required).

I just signed up and connect my instagram account (created new one for test) and I can delete or reply comments through this platform but on my own product i'm gettimg an error like `endpoint retired`.

I also tried to move API from the old one to Graph API but due to privacy updates, we don't have ability to upgrade new Graph API it says that

`Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active accounts due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform`

So If I have correct Instagram user access_token, how can I still delete or reply comments through API ?

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried to set a different version of API in your calls?

Comment: I tried on v1 on Instagram. Are there the newer version of Instagram  API? `https://api.instagram.com/v1/` this my main API call URL.